# Videos don't work

Tags: league-of-legends, technical-issues

Every video in the League of Legends client, whether it be a YouTube video or the videos of the champions' abilities, does not work.

It plays the sound completely fine as fine as I can tell, but the video is just moving lines and colors.

[image]

Comment: Comment why you are downvoting please....

Comment: Is your flash up-to-date? Do your youtube-videos work in your browser?

Comment: Are you playing on Mac or Windows?

Comment: I have an HP dv6 laptop, with an i7 3rd generation processor, 8GB of RAM, a Nvidia Geoforce GT 630M graphics card, and it is running Windows 64 bit. YouTube videos work completely fine in my browser (Google Chrome)

Comment: Yes! I have guessed that this is double GPU card issue ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**League of Legends** launcher uses **[Adobe Air](http://get.adobe.com/air/)** and [Adobe Flash Player](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/) technology. Check that you have it updated and lateast possible first.

If you have a **laptop** I will take a longshot that issue is connected with [automatic graphic card switching](http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=762202). Choose only **better GPU**, turn off and on LoL client.

If this not help check [Troubleshooting on this Wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Hope that this will help.

Comment: I set the LoL client to run with the high performance GPU and it didn't work...

Comment: This is sad. I have similar issue and it helped. What about GPU drivers?

Answer (score 1):

Had the exact same issue and fixed it using the following method, hope it works for you!

1. Play a youtube video within the LoL client (featured videos in main menu for example)
2. Hit "Ctrl+Shift+Esc" to bring up the task manager
3. Look for "Adobe AIR Debug Launcher" and right click it, then click "open file location"
4. Windows explorer should have popped up with the location of the executable file thats giving you troubles (the file itself will be highlighted).  Right click it then go to "run with graphics processor" and the "change default processor".
5. Add the .exe to the nvidia setting client and change the preferred processor to High-performance Nvidia processor.
6. Restart the LoL client then test a video.
   Good lux!